# electron - context menu disappear after dialog is added

Tags: electron

electron

add `context menu` in renderer.js:

```js
//renderer.js
const { remote } = require('electron');
const myContextMenu = remote.Menu.buildFromTemplate ([
{ label: 'Exit', role: 'quit' },
{ label: 'Minimize', role: 'minimize' },
{ type: 'separator' },
{ label: 'Start', click() { console.log('Start the app') } }
])

window.addEventListener('contextmenu', (event) => {
 event.preventDefault();
 myContextMenu.popup();
})
```

this part works.

---

after adding dialog:

```js
const dialog = remote.dialog,
WIN = remote.getCurrentWindow();

let filePaths = dialog.showOpenDialog(WIN)
console.log('filePaths)
```

my `context menu` disappear.

What's wrong?

---

Comment: console.log('filePaths') missing '

Comment: @tpikachu you are right! I wonder if I should delete my question